# How to use a controller's methods in a different GSP?

Tags: grails, view, controller

I have a user controller which is mostly CRUD and spring toolsuite can autogenerate basic functional views for the crud.

```
package rms

import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException

class UserController {

static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]

def index() {
    redirect(action: "list", params: params)
}

def list(Integer max) {
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    [userInstanceList: User.list(params), userInstanceTotal: User.count()]
}

def create() {
    [userInstance: new User(params)]
}

def save() {
    def userInstance = new User(params)
    if (!userInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [userInstance: userInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), userInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: userInstance.id)
}

def show(Long id) {
    def userInstance = User.get(id)
    if (!userInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    [userInstance: userInstance]
}

def edit(Long id) {
    def userInstance = User.get(id)
    if (!userInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    [userInstance: userInstance]
}

def update(Long id, Long version) {
    def userInstance = User.get(id)
    if (!userInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    if (version != null) {
        if (userInstance.version > version) {
            userInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure",
                      [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User')] as Object[],
                      "Another user has updated this User while you were editing")
            render(view: "edit", model: [userInstance: userInstance])
            return
        }
    }

    userInstance.properties = params

    if (!userInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "edit", model: [userInstance: userInstance])
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), userInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: userInstance.id)
}

def delete(Long id) {
    def userInstance = User.get(id)
    if (!userInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    try {
        userInstance.delete(flush: true)
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
    }
    catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: id)
    }
}
}
```

then i tried to use its method in a different gsp i have created not under the view/user. I copied the table html and the paginate html code from the autogenerated view/user/list. The rest in my own view is just static html headers and footers so it should not be important.

```
<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <g:sortableColumn property="username" title="${message(code: 'user.username.label', default: 'Username')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="password" title="${message(code: 'user.password.label', default: 'Password')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="dateOfBirth" title="${message(code: 'user.dateOfBirth.label', default: 'Date Of Birth')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="contactNumber" title="${message(code: 'user.contactNumber.label', default: 'Contact Number')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="employeeID" title="${message(code: 'user.employeeID.label', default: 'Employee ID')}" />

                    <g:sortableColumn property="employeeStatus" title="${message(code: 'user.employeeStatus.label', default: 'Employee Status')}" />

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <g:each in="${userInstanceList}" status="i" var="userInstance">
                <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">

                    <td><g:link action="show" id="${userInstance.id}">${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "username")}</g:link></td>

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "password")}</td>

                    <td><g:formatDate date="${userInstance.dateOfBirth}" /></td>

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "contactNumber")}</td>

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "employeeID")}</td>

                    <td>${fieldValue(bean: userInstance, field: "employeeStatus")}</td>

                </tr>
            </g:each>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="pagination">
            <g:paginate total="${userInstanceTotal}" />
        </div>
```

Whenever i use the sortable columns under my own view it is redirected to the view/user/list and then the paginate cant find the value of the total which is userInstanceTotal. There is also no data under my own view but the created data is working on the autogenerated CRUD view/user/list after i created it with view/user/create

Comment: Why dont you generate controllers for each view that you have?

Comment: the idea is that this CRUD for the users can be used for other pages. Since i will have an admin then a normal user. The admin has access to all the CRUD. but the user will just need to have to show the list

Comment: If you are calling the `list()` method from your GSP, then it will render the `list.gsp` page because return statement in the `list()` method does not specify a view.  It just returns a map, and convention dictates that it will find the `(method).gsp` page, in this case `list.gsp`.

Comment: @dspies so how do you use this list method with a different gsp i tried this `render(view:"differentView", params: params)` but it gave me an error _java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Map$Entry_ when im using the `<g:sortableColumn params="[conroller='user']" property="username" title="${message(code: 'user.username.label', default: 'Username')}" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a traditional request/response application, if you want to use the same controller action (e.g. `list()`) for two different GSPs, you would need to put a conditional in the controller action to determine what page to render, such as `request.getHeader('referer')` or by passing an additional param to determine what page you are on.  I would recommend against this, however, as it violates the single responsibility principle.  Instead, I would opt to create another controller method, such as

### In UserController

```
  myList(Integer max){
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 10, 100)
    return [userInstanceList: User.list(params), userInstanceTotal: User.count()]
  }
```

This is not very DRY, but you could move the common parts to a service if your requirements become more complicated.

### In myList.gsp

Copy `list.gsp` to `myList.gsp`.  Everthing is the same except the pagination tag, change the pagination tag to include `action`

```
<g:paginate action='myList' total="${userInstanceTotal}" />
```

Note the addition of `action='myList'`.  If you don't supply this, it will default to `list()`

Comment: im not familiar with this service. can you demonstrate at least the basics, like how do you use it

Comment: I just meant, put common functionality such as database access methods into a standard Grails Service, such as `class UserService { listUsers(){}}` that is injected into the Controller via `def userService`, but this is only necessary if your controller methods get more involved.

Answer (score 0):

Grails uses the actions of you current controller by default.

You can override this behaviour for most tags using the `controller` and `action` attributes. For example the `<g:paginate />` supports these attributes:

```
<g:paginate controller="user" action="list" total="${userInstanceTotal}" />
```

In this case `UserController.list()` will be called to receive the next/previous page.

Unfortunately the `<g:sortableColumn />` tag does not seem to have these attributes. However, it supports a `mapping` attribute that can be used to reference a [named url mapping](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.2/guide/single.html#namedMappings).

```
static mappings = {
    name userList: "/userList" {
    controller = 'user'
    action = 'list'
}

<g:sortableColumn mapping="userList" .. />
```

Comment: i added `controller="user" action="list"` but it still says it's missing the required attribute [total] which is supposed to be `${userInstanceTotal}`